# Write string if a specific participant has a specific string in another table

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

**I want to see if a patient is willing to participate in our trial on ICT therapy.**

In sheet1 I have a patientID-column and I want a ResearchOK-column that would write "Yes", if in sheet2 the OK-column says "Yes" for the same patientID (which has an adjacent column in sheet2). Simple enough, right? Well...

The problem is that in sheet2 the OK-column has a lot of empty values with the same patientID in the adjacent column. So the patient is a participant if there is one "Yes" for his patientID on OK-column, and not if there are none. This threw off all of my attempts.

Please let me know if I'm making no sense, I'll help however I can. I provided two simplified screen captures for illustration.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzXKW.jpg)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnsBc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A;Sheet1!A1;Sheet2!B:B;"Yes") > 0; "Yes"; "")
```

Comment: The formula is written on excel 2007!